# Avoid Duplicate Record MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, duplicates, record

How can I validate to prevent a duplicate of a record.
This is my Controller (Create)

```
[HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]

public ActionResult Create(Project mcpc, HttpPostedFileBase file, 
[Bind(Include = 
"ProjectID,NumberMCP,EngineerID,SiteLocationID,nameProject,Ptype, MCPcontent, Proj, ContentType")] Project project)
        {
          try
            {
                if (seg.ValidaAcceso(Session["AppCode"].ToString(), Convert.ToInt16(Session["UsrRol"]), "Crear"))
                {                           
                    if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
                    {                          
                            string ds = file.FileName.Substring(file.FileName.Length - 3);
                        string p = string.Empty;
                        p = Server.MapPath("~/UploadFiles/");
                        file.SaveAs(p + file.FileName);

                        if (file.ContentLength > 0)
                        {
                            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(file.InputStream);
                            byte[] buffer = br.ReadBytes(file.ContentLength);

                            using (db)
                            {
 mcpc.Proj = file.FileName;
                                mcpc.ContentType = file.ContentType;
                                mcpc.MCPcontent = buffer;
                                db.Projects.Add(mcpc);
                                db.SaveChanges();
                            }

                        }
                        ViewBag.EngineerID = new SelectList(db.Engineers, "EngineerID", "eName", project.EngineerID);
                        ViewBag.SiteLocationID = new SelectList(db.SiteLocations, "SiteLocationID", "nameSL", project.SiteLocationID);


                        return RedirectToAction("Index");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        TempData["Message"] = "No se elegió ningún archivo.";
                        return RedirectToAction("Create");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    return seg.NotAccess();

                }

            }

            catch /*(Exception ex)*/
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

***I'm using ProjectID as Identity primary key, and NumberMCP cant have duplicate.***

Ive been looking around about how to show the user that can not be possible to create a record because its already taken. 
So this may be a really simple question but what is the best way to prevent the user from trying to enter duplicate records? *(New programming)*

Answer (score 0):

Check for the possible duplicated field before attempting to add it to the db. If it exists, return an error message to the user, otherwise add it.

```
using (db)
{
    if (db.Projects.Any(p => p.NumberMCP == mcpc.NumberMCP)) 
    {
        // Handle error here
    }
    mcpc.Proj = file.FileName;
    mcpc.ContentType = file.ContentType;
    mcpc.MCPcontent = buffer;
    db.Projects.Add(mcpc);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: The answer or resolution to what I was looking was this: I put his on my class [Remote("Validation", "Projects", ErrorMessage = "Is already in used.")] using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
Add in the controller I put 

 public JsonResult Validation(string NumberMCP)
        {
            PMPDIDBEntities db = new PMPDIDBEntities();
            var result = true;
            bool ExistsInDatabase = db.Projects.Any(x => x.NumberMCP == NumberMCP);
            if (ExistsInDatabase) result = false;
            return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }